# Outlook Desktop Alert doesn't work while in a full screen RDP Window

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, 64-bit, microsoft-outlook, remote-desktop

User  isn't getting his Outlook desktop notifications while remoted into another PC/server.

It works on my Windows XP machine with Outlook 2010 SP1 in a maximised RDP window so I'm wondering if it's either A: a bug or (hopefully) B: a check box somewhere?

I've managed to reproduce the issue. On both machines, running Windows 7 x64bit with Outlook 2010 SP1 x64bit but I can't solve it!!!

Help's much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

RDP is essentially a terminal services session into your PC, so I think this 
[Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983063) applies (in short: this is a bug in Outlook 2010).

Comment: Thanks but that isn't the issue I'm having. the Outlook window is open on the local machine, and I'm remoted into various other RDP sessions. If Outlook was being used on a remote PC that would make sense, but unfortunately it isn't! :(